# Does the 1928 version of Mickey Mouse in Steamboat Willie lack gloves and shoes?

Tags: law, copyright

According to [CNN's article, *"An early version of Disney’s Mickey Mouse will enter the public domain on January 1"*](https://www.cnn.com/2023/12/30/business/disney-copyright-mickey-mouse-expire-2024/index.html),

> There are differences between the 1928 Mickey and the company’s mascot today. The Mickey of “Steamboat Willie” **lacks the current Mickey’s gloves and oversized shoes**, and his eyes are small black ovals without pupils.

Is it true that the 1928 version of Mickey lacks gloves and shoes? Let's ignore the qualifier of "oversized", and just go with shoes.

Comment: Related: Mickey Mouse has changed throughout the years - [Mickey Mouse Neotenia](https://www.google.com/search?q=mickey+mouse+neotenia)

Comment: @Jonathan: Did you mean to link to a Google search?  That will give different results for different people.

Comment: This question can be answered by watching an easily accessible  public domain movie!

Comment: "Oversize" would mean that the shoes are too big for his feet. How big are the li'll rodent's feet, anyway?

Comment: @jwodder: Yes. I read the original idea in [Stephen Jay Gould's book The Panda's Thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Panda%27s_Thumb_(book)), and didn't find a direct link. I found one now: [A Biological Homage to Mickey Mouse](https://faculty.uca.edu/benw/biol4415/papers/Mickey.pdf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Disney, as hosted currently,

> Watch Mickey Mouse's classic cartoon debut and see what made Walt's little hero a movie star.

Below which there is a [video of the original Steamboat Willie](https://video.disney.com/watch/steamboat-willie-4ea9de5180b375f7476ada2c)

With the opening slide that looks like this,

[image: Steamboat Willie]

So this is what he looked like before the movie started,

[image: Mickey Mouse]

And this is him from the last slide "The End".

[image: Mickey at the end]

In both of these slides you can see shoes and gloves. Whether that makes it [public domain is a legal question (link to Legal StackExchange).](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/98485/218)

Comment: The title card is dated 1929 (MCMXXIX), and the title and end cards are similar to each other in style and noticeably different from the cartoon itself. It's likely that they weren't in the original version from 1928—[see also this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/98491).

Comment: That said, his shoes in the cartoon itself are basically the same as those in the title/end cards, and it appears the black oval is supposed to be his pupil, not his whole eye (frame-step through him opening his eyes at 0:30).

Comment: But if you watch the actual cartoon, Mickey doesn't wear gloves.

Comment: @Barmar So what? The actual cartoon is not the only thing that just entered public domain. All the surrounding bits created at the same time also entered it, unless there's a reason their copyright should have a different length. If the title card was created at the same time, it's public domain now. If the title card was created a year later, then of course it will enter public domain a year later.

Comment: @user253751 as noted, the surrounding bits were not created at the same time, but a year later.

Comment: @OrangeDog While possible, it's far from certain. The only evidence for 1929, is a claim which we have no reason to believe is factual that people are assuming is only applicable to the cover slide because we know (common knowledge) the movie itself premiered in 1928.

Comment: @EvanCarroll the copyright year being written on it is perfectly sufficient evidence. Unless you are claiming that Disney have faked this video clip and changed the year to be one later than it originally said? If Steamboat Willie were not released in 1928 then this question wouldn't be being asked this year.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'm stating that Disney may have just lied about the copyright, and written 1929 on a film that was released in 1928 because it was very close to 1929 anyway (it was released in the middle of November). This is a fairly regular marketing tactic because it makes it seem newer: the same reason that you could buy a 2024 Pickup truck 5 months ago (with ease). Moreover, Disney totally botched this Copyright notice, and it seems likely it wasn't created by a lawyer that knew what they were doing: https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2008-aug-22-fi-mickey22-story.html

Comment: @EvanCarroll, I'm pretty sure Disney wouldn't post-date the copyright -- the 1909 act specifies a $100 fine for a false statement of copyright, and one of the later amendments adds specific penalties for false dating (pre-dating is taken at face value, post-dating voids the copyright).